# Best practices for authentication in AngularJS for my requirements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am using angularJS and expressJS with NodeJS. I need its authorization methods to work the existing infrastructure.

For the existing infrastructure, we already have a single sign-on security application. It validates username/password and then sets a session ID in the session cookie and the database. When a user go our other applications, they  check if the session ID in user browser exists in our database and if it is expired or not; if the session ID is valid, the user is allowed access.

For my new project, I plan to protect the expressJS API since it access the database. I plan to create a check session ID function that check if a session ID is valid in the database. I require every expressJS API function to have a session ID parameter and call the check session ID function on the passed in parameter. Next I plan to use cookie service in anuglarJS to access the session ID stored in session cookie and pass that to every expressJS API called in angularJS.

With my existing infrastructure, do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: Sounds good. However make sure to test it extensively.   And definetly have a look at nodejs crypto, especially pbkdf2 :)

Answer (score 0):

As you use session, you don't need to check the session ID.
Instead, save some user profile field such as email into session, and check if profile exist in every request.

improvements:
1. Destroy and create new session after login
2. Set timeout for session, may be 30 mins
3. Disable cross domain request
4. Finally, use middleware function to check the authentication in every request
e.g.
`app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
checkAuth(req, res, next);
});`

in function checkAuth, check profile in session, call next() if positive, else give response with access deny

Comment: how would I make sure my expressJS API are protected then in your algorithm?

Comment: It's not yet well protected, 
you still have so many issues to concern.
checkout the security practice of expressJS:
http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html
you may also dig into OWASP to find your most concerned issues and try to hack it one by one by yourself or use security check tools such as ZAP:
http://www.zaproxy.org/